# SwingWorker: How to delegate values from the process() method to another class

Tags: java, swingworker

In my program I have a swingworker, so that the user can access the GUI while the program itself is still running.

Is there a way to return the values I declare in the `process()` method to another class? The reason I ask is the following:

The GUI shows among other things charts, which should update if the user pushes on a button. Within the `doInBackground()` method an ArrayList is permanent updated. In this ArrayList are values that the charts should show, so every time the user pushes the button the chart should show the values that are actually in the Array List

The code is the following

```
 protected Void doInBackground()
{
    SaveList savelist = new SaveList();


    while(true)
    {
     try
     {
            savelist.updateSaveList();
            publish((SaveList) savelist);

            Thread.sleep(100);
     }

     catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



    protected void process(SaveList savelist) 
    {
     this.savelistsize = savelist.saveListSize();
     this.trueLabeled = savelist.trueLabeled();
     this.falseLabeled = savelist.falseLabeled();
     this.trueLabeledPercent = savelist.trueLabeled()/savelist.saveListSize();
     this.falseLabeledPercent = savelist.falseLabeled()/savelist.saveListSize();
    }`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to delegate some of the logic done in `process()` to a different class. In that case make a named subclass of the `SwingWorker` and initialize it with the delegate instance.

Example:

```
public class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, X> { // X - I don't know the type of SaveList elements

    private MyDelegate delegate;

    public MySwingWorker(MyDelegate delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    protected Void doInBackground() { ... }

    protected void process(SaveList savelist) {
        delegate.doSomethingWith(savelist);
    }
}
```

and you can then implement your logic in `MyDelegate.doSomethingWith(SaveList)`

Comment: First of all: Yes you understood me correctly :-)
So thank you, I'll give it a try!

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to StackOverflow with your first question :) Hint: if you find an answer helpful, you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow to the left of the answer. Also, as the person asking the question, you can accept an answer that helped you best by ticking the mark to the left of the answer. Good luck!